# Query something on the other end of a has many through association

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I want to filter through the results of a has many through association query. Do I have to do this with Elixir or can I use Ecto to do the job in the database?

## Setup

```
mix phx.new shop
cd shop
mix echo.create
mix phx.gen.html Accounting Invoice invoices number issues_on:date
mix phx.gen.html Accounting Product products name category
mix phx.gen.html Accounting LineItem line_items 
                                     invoice_id:references:invoices 
                                     product_id:references:products
mix ecto.migrate
```

**priv/repo/seeds.exs**

```
{:ok, invoice1} = Shop.Accounting.create_invoice(%{number: "1", issued_on: "2017-01-01"})
{:ok, invoice2} = Shop.Accounting.create_invoice(%{number: "2", issued_on: "2017-01-01"})
{:ok, invoice3} = Shop.Accounting.create_invoice(%{number: "3", issued_on: "2017-01-02"})

{:ok, banana} = Shop.Accounting.create_product(%{name: "Banana", category: "Fruits"})
{:ok, potato} = Shop.Accounting.create_product(%{name: "Potato", category: "Vegetables"})

Shop.Accounting.create_line_item(%{invoice_id: invoice1.id, product_id: banana.id})
Shop.Accounting.create_line_item(%{invoice_id: invoice2.id, product_id: banana.id})
Shop.Accounting.create_line_item(%{invoice_id: invoice2.id, product_id: potato.id})
Shop.Accounting.create_line_item(%{invoice_id: invoice3.id, product_id: potato.id})
```

### Schema

**lib/shop/accounting/invoice.ex**

```
schema "invoices" do
  field :issued_on, :date
  field :number, :string
  has_many :line_items, Shop.Accounting.LineItem
  has_many :products, through: [:line_items, :product]

  timestamps()
end
```

**lib/shop/accounting/line_item.ex**

```
schema "line_items" do
  belongs_to :invoice, Shop.Accounting.Invoice
  belongs_to :product, Shop.Accounting.Product

  timestamps()
end
```

## Query invoices for vegetables preloading them

How can I query all `invoices` from the 1st of January to the 5th of January including the `products` which have the value `Vegetables` for a `category`.
It's ok if they have `line_items` of fruits too. I just want to make sure that there is no `invoice` which ONLY has fruits but no vegetable. With this seeds it would be the invoice 2 and 3.

I know how to filter `invoices` with Elixir. But I'm wondering if I can solve this in the database with Ecto faster. Is there a way to filter it with Ecto?

```
import Ecto.Query
alias Shop.Accounting.Invoice
alias Shop.Repo

{:ok, starts_on} = Date.from_erl({2017, 1, 1})
{:ok, ends_on} = Date.from_erl({2017, 1, 5})


query = from i in Invoice, where: i.issued_on >= ^starts_on,
                           where: i.issued_on <= ^ends_on,
                           preload: [:products]
invoices = Repo.all(query)

# Here I would loop through invoices to filter the once 
# with vegetables.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Ecto.Query` `join`: https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#join/5

In your case, it will be:

```
query = from i in Invoice, where: i.issued_on >= ^starts_on,
                           where: i.issued_on <= ^ends_on,
                           join: p in assoc(i, :products),
                           where: p ...,
                           preload: [:products]
```

and work on condition you want.

Also, I often used these examples when I learned Ecto: https://elixirnation.io/references/ecto-query-examples

They are a bit outdated, but generally fine.

Comment: Have you tested it? I have a feeling it's more complicated than that and would probably require a nested query.

Comment: A simple join like this will duplicate the invoice for each product `p` that matches the `where` condition, e.g. if it's `p.category == "Vegetables"` and an invoice has multiple products which are vegetables, the returned list will have multiple copies of that invoice. Probably needs a group_by or something as well.

Comment: Or distinct query.